# Firebase USer Registration - Screens won't go away

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to implement Firebase Authentication into my App, and when an existing user installs the latest version the authentication screen won't disappear no matter how many times they sign in.

Its really odd - was working perfectly until I moved to a new computer.

It doesn't seem to apply to new accounts, but existing accounts that were previously set up can't login to the new version of the app.

```
mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                //user is signed in
                onSignedInInialise(user.getDisplayName());

            } else {
                //user is signed out
                onSignedOutCleanup();
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()))
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }

        }
    };



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            String uid = user.getUid();
            String userName = user.getDisplayName();
            String userEmail = user.getEmail();
            Uri userProfilePic = user.getPhotoUrl();
            createUserInFirebaseHelper(uid, userName, userEmail);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello " + userName + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == GPS_PERMISSION) {

        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if (provider != null) {
            getLocation();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You must enable Gps to get your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}



    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
        mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
    detachDatabaseReadListener();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added SHA-1 of your new computer to Firebase Console of your app?

Comment: Yamko you're a legend.  So simple, can't believe I missed it. :)